# Search for an unknown string between two brackets

Tags: text-processing

```
Oct 24 10:18:43 reliant3 sshd[67299]: Accepted password for root from 10.51.21.57 port 60097 ssh2
```

I am searching for the word password. Once I find it I want to find anything that is associated with the `sshd[67299]` number and print it.

Comment: How many sshd lines (rounded to the nearest power of 10) are in the log file? A simple solution using only `awk` is possible, but it requires memory in proportion to the number of unique sshd PIDs in the log file. A `grep` solution uses very little memory but would require at least two passes through the file.

Comment: This is either trivial (if you only care about the lines containing the magic word), or interesting, but unclearly presented and missing the rest of the input format and other requirements (if you want all lines from the relevant ssh processes).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "Oct 24 10:18:43 reliant3 sshd[67299]: Accepted password for root from 10.51.21.57 port 60097 ss" | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
67299
```

(discard all, par what is in the brackets).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
grep password my_log.txt | sed 's/.*sshd\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

`grep password my_log.txt` gets all lines with password in it.

`sed 's/.*sshd\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'` finds the `[]`'s after `sshd` and gets the PID inside of it.

You didn't specify this in your question but you could also pipe this to `sort -u` to filter out duplicates.

## Update

While less readable in my opinion you could also do it all on one `sed` line.

```
sed -e '/password/!d;s/.*sshd\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' my_log.txt
```

Comment: What is the reason to use additional *grep* while *sed* have address options?

Comment: @Costas I have updated my answer with a one liner from `sed`